# What's wrong with this GUI class?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, error-handling

For a school project, I have to make a java GUI that takes in three arrays, and puts them into a GUI. However, I'm struggling with the WordGUI class.
I keep getting this error:

```
C:\Users\anon\OneDrive\Desktop\Project1\src\Project1.java:76:31
                           java: '.class' expected
```

Here's the code:

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    
    public class WordGUI{
    
    
        private  static int g,f;
        private  static String[] myArray1,myArray2,myArray3;
    
        public WordGUI(int g, int f, String[] myArray1, String[] myArray2, String[] myArray3){
            this.g = g;
            this.f = f;
            this.myArray1 = myArray1;
            this.myArray2 = myArray2;
            this.myArray3 = myArray3;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
    
            JFrame myWordGUI = new JFrame("Words");
            myWordGUI.setSize(400,200);
            myWordGUI.setLocation(100,100);
            myWordGUI.setTitle("Lots of Words!!");
            myWordGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            myWordGUI.setVisible(true);
    
            Container myContentPane=myWordGUI.getContentPane();
    
            myWordGUI.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    
            TextArea myTextArea1 = new TextArea();
            TextArea myTextArea2 = new TextArea();
            TextArea myTextArea3 = new TextArea();
    
            myContentPane.add(myTextArea1);
            myContentPane.add(myTextArea2);
            myContentPane.add(myTextArea3);
            for(int h=0; h<g; h++){
                myTextArea1.append(myArray1[h]+"\n");
            }
    
            int p = 0;
            while(p<(g-f)){
                myTextArea2.append(myArray2[p]+"\n");
                p+=1;
            }
    
            for(int q=0; myArray3[q]!= null; q++){
                myTextArea3.append(myArray3[q]+"\n");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Also, here is the Project1 code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;



public class Project1
{

    private static void selectionSort
    (String[] array, int length) {//short arr
        for ( int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++ ) {
            int indexLowest = i;
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < length; j++ )
                if ( array[j].compareTo(array[indexLowest])<0 )
                    indexLowest = j;
            if ( array[indexLowest] != array[i] ) {
                String temp = array[indexLowest];
                array[indexLowest] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }  // if
        } // for i
    } // method selectionSort
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //read file to string 'content'
        String content= "";
        FileReader fr =
                new FileReader("Project1Input.txt");

        int i;
        while ((i=fr.read()) != -1)
            content+= (char)i;
//        Remove special chars:  .,()
        content= content.replaceAll("[.,)(]"," ");
        //split it into words with string tokenizer
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(content);
        int j =0;
        String[] allWords = new String[st.countTokens()];
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0;st.hasMoreTokens(); k+=1){
            allWords[k]=st.nextToken();

        }
        //Separate into arrays of valid and invalid words
        String[] validWords = new String[k];
        String[] invalidWords = new String[k];
        int v = 0;
        int w = 0;
        for(int m =0; m< k; m++){
            if(allWords[m].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                validWords[v]=allWords[m];
                v++;
            }
            else{
                invalidWords[w]=allWords[m];
                w++;
            }
        }
        //sort array of strings
        selectionSort(allWords, k);
        //make array the right size
        int t = 0;
        for(t = 0; invalidWords[t]!= null; t++){

        }
        String[] allValidWords = new String[k-t];
        for (int y = 0; y<(k-t); y++){
            allValidWords[y]= validWords[y];
        }

        WordGUI(k,t,allWords[],allValidWords[],invalidWords[]);

    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a syntax error somewhere?
I'm not sure how to fix this. I've been obsessing over this for a while and haven't found the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Also error seems to be related to `Project1.java` but since your class is public and is named `WordGUI` I am assuming it is inside `WordGUI.java`, so you may not be showing right code.

Comment: Yes. WordGUI is in WordGUI.java. Project1 is in Project1.java

Comment: In `Project1` instead of `WordGUI(k,t,allWords[],allValidWords[],invalidWords[]);` you probably want to remove each `[]` (as it is only used while *declaring* variable, not while *passing* it) and add `new` since you probably want to invoke constructor with those parameters. So replace it with `new WordGUI(k,t,allWords,allValidWords,invalidWords);` (you may also want to add `WordGUI wordGUI =` before it to have variable via which you could interact with that instance).